# How to mock a function which have input is an exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, .net-core, mocking

I am writing a Unit Test in .netcore C# for a function. In that function, I need to setup a function for mock object. This function have input is an Exception. I try below solution, it compile ok but fail in run-time. Please help.

Need to test function:

```
    public void MyFunction()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "...");
            ...
        }
    }
```

In Unit Test , I do setup as below:

```
_loggerMock.Setup(l => l.LogError(It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null));
```

Error when running UT:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: l => l.LogError(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), new[] {  })
>   Extension methods (here: LoggerExtensions.LogError) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

Comment: `LogError` is an extension method. You need to mock the `Log<TState>(...)` method on the `ILogger` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the guideline from Simple Ged's comment. And it works now.

Here is the code:

```
_loggerMock.Setup(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()));
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it doesn't work for me. I confirmed via debugging that my code-under-test calls `logger.LogError(ex, "Error message")` multiple times but if I then attempt to verify the number of calls, it tells me it isn't called at all... The call to .Verify(): _`loggerMock.Verify(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()), Times.AtLeastOnce);`

Answer (score 0):

The code above not working for me as well.
The logger is correctly invoked but verification failed.

Here is the working code for me

```
_loggerMock.Verify(x => x.Log(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception?, string>>()),Times.AtLeastOnce);
```

Try use **It.IsAnyType** rather than **object**

https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/mocking-ilogger-with-moq